# What country codes are these?

Tags: c#, .net, country-codes

i have some existing code, and i wonder what kind of country codes they are?
Are the somehow mappable to codes somewhere in the .NET framework?

```
        <option value="4">Albania</option>
        <option value="7">Andorra</option>
        <option value="21">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="1">Antigua And Barbuda</option>

        <option value="23">Argentina</option>
        <option value="59">Aruba</option>
        <option value="66">Australia</option>
        <option value="390">Austria</option>
        <option value="463">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="477">Bahrain</option>

        <option value="479">Barbados</option>
        <option value="491">Belarus</option>
        <option value="493">Belgium</option>
        <option value="525">Belize</option>
        <option value="529">Bolivia</option>
        <option value="541">Bosnia Herzegovina</option>
```

Comment: I don't think so, probably they match their entries in the *countries* table of a DB used by the application.

Comment: Kudos to whoever wrote that code without documenting this. If it was annoying to write it should be impossible to read.

Comment: @matteo: i didn't find one, unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

I suspect those codes represent an arbitrary key in a database somewhere, not a standard country code.

http://countrycode.org/

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Extract the content from this table: http://countrycode.org/, perhaps storing it as a comma delimited file. Then, in your application, look up the code associated with the country. **Note**: the copyright on the table is for personal noncommercial use only. http://countrycode.org/copyright

Comment: And do you see any correlation between those codes and the ones in the question?

Comment: No, but then again neither do the codes in the links that the others posted.